# Error handling in firebase? How to get response status?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Recently implemented validation when sending request to my firebase db. It works fine, however Im struggling with error handling. If there was some error with sending the data to firebase, I want to display user that he was unable to post his data due to lacking keys in his request (he missed some fields in the form).

What's **important**, Im able to catch the error if something went wrong:

```
users.set(values, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Here's what I get in the console:
[image]

Okey I got the error, but it's not really helpful... I mean, it is helpful, but for me, not for the user. Honestly I would prefer to get some object with **status** and the **body** of the error. But here I got... I don't know what's that, an error object?

**Q**: How am I able to differentiate between possible errors? Am I somehow able to get the **status** of that response?

So I could simply use it in my component:

```
users.set(values, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    if (err.status == 401) {
      alert('You didnt fill all the fields in the form!');
    } else if (err.status == 404) {
      alert('Something else went wrong...');
    }
  }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have error codes you can check.  There is only one type of error, and that's a violation of the security rules on the server.  When a security rule triggers an error in the SDK, there's no way to figure out which one or what condition was violated.  The SDK isn't designed to give helpful messages to the end user - it's designed to help you put data in the database.  How you choose to interact with the user is completely up to you.

If you want to check for errors, you'll have to do that yourself.  If you want the error checking to be done on the server, use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to make an endpoint to call that handles the data you want to add.